# Root folder of my React application conflicts with React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My React application is hosted at `www.mywebsite.com/myreact`

When I defined my routes, I've done something like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Although, it keeps complaining that `/myreact` is not defined in the route.

When I define it, that way:

```
<Route path="/myreact" component={App} />
```

and I try to access the URL `www.mywebsite.com/myreact/login`, the browser throw a 404 error.

But I can access `www.mywebsite.com/myreact` properly though.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try adding `myreact` to the login route as well? `path="myreact/login"`

Comment: Just tried, it doesn't work...

Comment: try using browserHistory from react-router and your routes like path='/' & path='/login'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a custom `history` object with a different basename for your apps 'root' url. with the `useRouterHistory` enhancement when creating the history object

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#userouterhistorycreatehistory

some relavent comments in [this github issue thread](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/353)

```
import { createHistory } from 'history';
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router';

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: '/myreact'
});
```

your routes files should now work using `browserHistory`

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: This work perfectly if I create a link to access the login page from the root page. Although if I try to access /myreact/login directly entering the URL, that's when I get the 404 error. Any suggestion?

Comment: this is an inherent trait of the `browserHistory` type of history. if you go to any route manually before the router is attached, you must make a server route and allow your client-side js take over. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory